# Exclamation marks added to URLs in Cordova

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I am developing a hybrid app using Cordova to wrap an existing React web application.

When I launch my App, once in a while the data does not get loaded and I noticed that the URLs use the `file://` protocol instead of `http://localhost:80803` and have an exclamation mark appended at the end.

How can I solve this?

See example below:

- `file:///api/metaData/!`
- `file:///sideNavigation/!`

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should use exact full path of the url? Just move `http://localhost:80803` into the variable and add to every url like `\`${baseUrl}/api/metaData/\``

Comment: Yes, or in alternative strip out final slashes and exlamation mark. These are workaround though. I would like to get to the root cause. Thanks

Comment: Have you read about [cordova-plugin-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)? It seems that it affects your application.

Comment: @Dracontis I am not using that plugin. Cordova by default uses the file protocol to get resources/assets from the device file system.
Relative paths starting with a slash default to `file://` without the third slash and that causes the fetch to fail. Solution AFAIK is to use a './' prefix for local resources and add the http/https prefix for remote resources.

Comment: Then you should post an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Dracontis I don't have an answer, the one I use is only a workaround (checking if an exclamation mark got appended and removing it before sending the http request).

Answer (score 1):

This is strange and I admit that never occurred to me but these are some tests that you should try:

1. Do you use react-router ? maybe It's the router that mess with the url, try using hash router in cordova app. I've found that it's way more solid.
2. How do you build the URL of those resources ? maybe it's something in the code that build the url.
3. From your screenshot I can see that you are trying using iOS, do you have the same problem using Android?
4. In iOS what engine are you using ? try the newest wkengine (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) if you haven't already used it
5. Have you tried a local server ? something like this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/wkwebview-engine-localhost

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1. Already using hash router (it wouldnt work otherwise), 3. More often on Android. Will try 4 and 5, thanks! :)